# TemplateControl.GetLocalResourceObject(string) does not work on deploy server

Tags: asp.net, deployment, resources

please help me with the following.

It works under VS 2010 development server, in .aspx file:
<%= GetLocalResourceObject("Title") %>

It does not work under win 2003, iis 6, in .aspx file, after deployment from web setup(.msi):
<%= GetLocalResourceObject("Title") %>

Same .dll, with same resources names in it (e.g. namespance.pagename.aspx.resource).
Does not help: iis restart, reinstalling, restarting computer. Resourcekey exists in resource file. There is resource in .dll.

The exception message:
"System.InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again."

Control's "meta:resourcekey" does not work too. Here is no exception. Just no text.

No help from research via googling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution. I have marked resx files as "Embeded resources" in "Build Action" property. They were not gotten by genereted aspx pages on deployment server. The .resx files should be moved with deployment files (.dll, .aspx, .ascx, etc). So marking them as "Content" will solve the problem.